# ASP.NET Core returns 404 for Angular Request

Tags: c#, asp.net, angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am using `ASP.NET Core` with `Angular 2+` , now I have a `Controller` like below :

```
  public class ValuesController : Controller
  {
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/values/get")]
    [ResponseCache(NoStore = true, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None)]
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
      return new string[] { "Hello", "DNT" };
    }
  }
```

and I have this for `startup.CS`

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(options =>
  {
    options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
  });

  services.AddMvc();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
  if (env.IsDevelopment())
  {
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
  }

  app.Use(async (context, next) => {
    await next();
    if (context.Response.StatusCode == 404 &&
        !Path.HasExtension(context.Request.Path.Value) &&
        !context.Request.Path.Value.StartsWith("/api/", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
      context.Request.Path = "/index.html";
      await next();
    }
  });
  app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
  app.UseDefaultFiles();
  app.UseStaticFiles();

}
```

and this `AppComponent` :

```
    export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private _httpService: Http) { }

  apiValues: string[] = [];

  ngOnInit() {
    this._httpService.get('api/values/get').subscribe(values => {
      this.apiValues = values.json() as string[];
    });
  }
}
```

when I run the project I get `404 (bad Request)` .

How can I solve this ?

Comment: if both angular and .net core are in the same project, just adjust your path as `/api/values/get` and it should work. or else if it doesn't show us how are you configuring angular inside .net core razor view

Answer (score 1):

Your route path is: "api/values/get".
So, use this path to your service call:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this._httpService.get('api/values/get').subscribe(values => {
      this.apiValues = values.json() as string[];
    });
  }
```

Comment: No it dosn't work . I tried it but same response . also I can not call with `Postman `too.